# Cutting output from sudo in a bash script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sudo

I am writing a script that is supposed to ask for user's password, do some stuff with it and eventually pass it to *sudo*. This is roughly how it looks:

```
echo "input password: "
read -s password
printf "\n"

echo $password | sudo -S <somecommand> | <what i need>
```

It all works as it should, but *sudo* outputs "[sudo] password for user: " whenever I call the script. I would like to cut this, but leave all other output.
This is what I've tried for :

```
grep -v -e "[sudo] password for user: "
awk -F"[ ',]+" '/[sudo] password for user:/{print $2}'
sed -En "s/[sudo[ password for user: '(.*)',/\1/p"
```

Obviously, since I am here none of this worked. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Is it possible to get the output of sudo command?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/485723)

Comment: You, sir, are a life saver!